# jQuery 2 sets of datepicker conflict

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have two sets of jQuery datepickers. One that loads on the page for desktop, the other in a modal for mobile. The first instance with two dates (Arrival Date & Departing Date) works as intended. But the second group of two dates in the mobile modal isn't passing either the arrival nor departure date `onclick` button submission.

Also the jQuery datepicker when selecting the arrival date it will not adjust the departure date +1 day automatically like I have managed on the Desktop set.  There seems to be a conflict between the two datepicker sets. I have `.split` the Month and Day so they maybe styled stacked instead of inline. The form is submitted to a third party booking engine. I don't understand what I have done wrong. I don't have duplicate ID's in my functions. Any help would be appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fb8vn.png)

Mobile datepicker depart date not updating after arrival date changed to after original departure date:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u27DV.png)

This specific page is running it in the top righthand corner on desktop button event on mobile: view [online version here](https://staging.clontarfcastle.ie/)

HTML:

```
 <form id="c5QuickBookDesktop" class="book-form-align" action="https://secure.clontarfcastle.ie/convert/site/Clontarf%20Castle%20Hotel/index.php" method="post">
        <div class="date">
          <label class="">Arrive</label>
          <input class="input-c060e3a from-month calendarWith2Dates cf-booking-month" for="from" title="Arrive" readonly="" type="text">
          <input class="cal calendarWith2Dates book-input-date from book-input input-lg" readonly="" type="text" value="Arrive">
          <input class="checkin" value="" name="checkin" type="hidden">
        </div>
        <div class="dateOut">
          <label class="" for="to">Depart</label>
          <input class="cf-booking-month to-month" for="to" title="Arrive" readonly="">
          <input class="calendarWith2Dates book-input-date to" readonly="" type="text" value="Depart">
        </div>
        <div class="nights hideInput">
          <input class="nights" name="nights" type="hidden" value="4">
        </div>
        <div class="">
          <button class="btn-light-effect" onclick="submitC5QuickBookDesktop()" type="button" value="Check Availability" target="_blank">Book Now</button>
          <input name="fw_submitted" type="hidden" value="1">
          <input class="av" value="search" name="av" type="hidden">
        </div>
      </form>
```

jQuery:

```
 /*<![CDATA[*/
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $(function () {
      $(".from").datepicker('setDate', new Date());
      $(".to").datepicker('setDate', '+1d');
      $('.checkin').datepicker('setDate', new Date());
  });
  $(".from-col").click(function () {
      $(".from").datepicker("show");
  });
  $(".to-col").click(function () {
      $(".to").datepicker("show");
  });
  $(".from").datepicker({
      dateFormat: "dd mm yy",
      minDate: 0,
      dateonly: true,
      altField: ".from-month",
      altFormat: "MM",
      onSelect: function (a) {
          var b = $(".from").datepicker("getDate");
          b.setDate(b.getDate() + 1);
          $(".to").datepicker("setDate", b);
          $(".to").datepicker("option", "minDate", b)
      },
      onClose:function(dateText, inst) {
          //dateText comes in as MM/DD/YY
          var dateArr = dateText.split(' ');
          var day = dateArr[0];
          var month = dateArr[1];
          var year = dateArr[2];
          //define select option values for
          //corresponding element
          $('select#arrmonth').val(month);
          $('select#arrday').val(day);
          $('select#arryear').val(year);
          $('.checkin').val(year + "-" + month + "-" + day);
          dateDifference();
      }
  });

  $(".to").datepicker({
      dateFormat: "dd mm yy",
      minDate: ".from" +1,
      altField: ".to-month",
      altFormat: "MM",
      onSelect: function () {
          var b = $(".from").datepicker("getDate");
          console.log(b);
          var a = $(".to").datepicker("getDate");
          if (a <= b) {
              var c = $(".to").datepicker("option", "minDate");
              $(".to").datepicker("setDate", c)
          }
      },
      onClose: function(dateText, inst) {                    
          var dateDep = dateText.split(' ');
          var day = dateDep[0];
          var month = dateDep[1];
          var year = dateDep[2];
          //define select option values for
          //corresponding element
          $('select#depmonth').val(month);
          $('select#depday').val(day);
          $('select#depyear').val(year);
          dateDifference();
      }
  });
  $(".checkin").datepicker({
      dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
      });
  function dateDifference() {
      if($(".from").val()!='' && $(".from").val()!='') {
          var diff = ($(".to").datepicker("getDate") - $(".from").datepicker("getDate")) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
          var roundedDiff = Math.round(diff);
          $('.nights').val(roundedDiff);
      }
  }
});


function submitC5QuickBookDesktop()
    {   
        //document.forms['c5TopQuickBook'].elements['checkin'].value = document.forms['c5TopQuickBook'].elements['.checkin-top'].val;
        document.forms['c5QuickBookDesktop'].submit();
    }

function submitC5QuickBookMobile()
    {   
        //document.forms['c5TopQuickBook'].elements['checkin'].value = document.forms['c5TopQuickBook'].elements['.checkin-top'].val;
        document.forms['c5QuickBookMobile'].submit();
    }
```